# jQuery not getting called in all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, fadein, fadeout

**Disclaimer:** I am new to jQuery.

I am trying to implement a fadeOut effect in jQuery for a `div` block, and then fadeIn effect on two other `div` blocks.

However, these effects are only working in the Chrome browser (i.e. they won't work in Safari, FireFox, Opera) which is rather perplexing to me.  I have tried clearing my cache in case it was storing an old file, but none of that seemed to do anything.

Basic idea (stored in `mainsite.js` file):

```
$("#videoThumbnail_XYZ").click(function () {
  $("#thumbnailDescription_XYZ").fadeOut(300);
  $("#videoPlayer_XYZ").delay(300).fadeIn(100);
  $("#videoHiddenOptions_XYZ").delay(300).fadeIn(100);
  });
```

So when a `div` tag with the id of `videoThumbnail_XYZ` is clicked, it starts the fadeOut and fadeIn calls on the other `div` tags.

I am loading my javascript files into the page in this order (so jQuery is loaded first):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
<script async="" type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/mainsite.js"></script>
```

Any guidance you could give is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is your code placed in the document ready handler? (i.e. `$(document).read(function(){...code here...})` ?

Comment: Can you post the HTML and JS?

Comment: Do you have this hosted somewhere for viewing? Can you use place the whole code here or http://jsfiddle.net/ for better debugging? Usually Chrome allows improper closings while other browsers will not tolerate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the DOM is fully loaded before your code runs.

A common way of doing this when using jQuery is to wrap your code like this.

```
$(function() {
    $("#videoThumbnail_XYZ").click(function () {
      $("#thumbnailDescription_XYZ").fadeOut(300);
      $("#videoPlayer_XYZ").delay(300).fadeIn(100);
      $("#videoHiddenOptions_XYZ").delay(300).fadeIn(100);
    });
});
```

This is a shortcut for wrapping your code in a `.ready()` handler, which ensure that the DOM is loaded before your code runs.

If you don't use some means of ensuring that the DOM is loaded, then the `#videoThumbnail_XYZ` element may not exist when you try to select it.

Another approach would be to place your javascript code after your content, but *inside* the closing `</body>` tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title>your title</title></head>
    <body>
        <!-- your other content -->

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
        <script async="" type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/mainsite.js"></script>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like you and Wazzy came up with the same thing +1 for shortening doc.ready.

Comment: @Loktar: One of them was faster ;)

Comment: Is doc.ready really too long?  To me, that just increases readability, particularly if the code is to be seen by others with less jQuery experience.

Comment: @Kyle: Purely personal preference. Many people like the long version better.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Patrick!  And also for the alternative approach

Answer (score 2):

If `mainsite.js` is being included before your `div` is rendered, that might be throwing the browsers for a loop.  Try wrapping this around your `click` handler setup:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// your function here
});
```

That'll make sure that isn't run before the DOM is ready.

Also, you might consider putting the fadeIn calls in the callback function of your fadeOut, so if you decide to change the duration later on, you only have to change it in one place.

The way that'd look is like this:

```
$("#thumbnailDescription_XYZ").fadeOut(300,function(){
  $("#videoPlayer_XYZ").fadeIn(100);
  $("#videoHiddenOptions_XYZ").fadeIn(100);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Kyle, good point about the callback function since it has the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

While JavaScript provides the load event for executing code when a page is rendered, this event does not get triggered until all assets such as images have been completely received. In most cases, the script can be run as soon as the DOM hierarchy has been fully constructed. The handler passed to `.ready()` is guaranteed to be executed after the **DOM is ready**, so this is usually the best place to attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#videoThumbnail_XYZ").click(function () {
        $("#thumbnailDescription_XYZ").fadeOut(300);
        $("#videoPlayer_XYZ").delay(300).fadeIn(100);
        $("#videoHiddenOptions_XYZ").delay(300).fadeIn(100);
    });
});
```

All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:

```
* $(document).ready(handler)
* $().ready(handler) (this is not recommended)
* $(handler)
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you have a delay set to the same duration your fadeOut is, I would recommend instead of delaying which in essence your waiting for the animation to complete that instead you use the callback function.

```
$("#videoThumbnail_XYZ").click(function () {
  $("#thumbnailDescription_XYZ").fadeOut(300, function() {
      $("#videoPlayer_XYZ").fadeIn(100);
      $("#videoHiddenOptions_XYZ").fadeIn(100);
  });
});
```